# Make a packaged EXE file

Tags: windows, temporary-files

I want to create a single EXE file that contains a program with multiple files and folders.
What I refer to with this is that I need an EXE file that unpacks itself in %TEMP% and then execute the EXE that it extracted.

I also want it to be silent (no window opens until the packaged EXE is executed).

Is there any tool that allows this to be made?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [softwarerecs.se],  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).